# How can I solve this expression for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to solve for $x$ given that

\begin{equation}
e^{-x}-\gamma-\eta e^{-\lambda(z-x)} = 0
\end{equation}

where $\gamma, \eta, \lambda$ are positive constants and $z$ is a real number.

Answer (score 2):

If you make change of variables $y = \mathrm e^x$ you obtain a power equation in $y$:
$$
  (\eta \mathrm e^{-\lambda z} )y^{1+\lambda}+\gamma y - 1 = 0
$$
which you can solve analytically for $\lambda \in \{-1,0,1,2,3\}$, however for other values of $\lambda$ I'm think there are no analytical solutions, so my best hope would be for numerical one. It also makes sense to check for which values of parameters there are positive roots.

Comment: That is helpful, would you please provide me a hint how to follow a similar strategy with the edits to the initial equality?

Comment: @Duna: not sure I understood you

Comment: There's a term, $e^{\lambda x}$, in the original equation, Ilya, and I don't see how you made it disappear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: my bad, was sure there was just minus.